# El comando OPEN en Tcl

Tags: tcl

¿Para que sirve el comando `open` en Tcl?

Estoy desarrollando en Linux.

Comment: ¿Qué información buscaste antes de preguntar? ¿qué intentaste y por qué estás preguntando?

Answer (score 0):

TCL "Tool Command Language" o "lenguaje de herramientas de comando"

Es un lenguaje de script creado por John Ousterhout

Se utiliza principalmente para el desarrollo rápido de prototipos, aplicaciones "script", interfaces gráficas y pruebas. La combinación de Tcl con Tk (del inglés Tool Kit) es conocida como Tcl/Tk, y se utiliza para la creación de interfaces gráficas.

Se pensó inicialmente para unir programas sencillos en C, dando forma a una aplicación sencilla.

**Open** Permite ejecutar un programa y comunicarse con el usando la entrada / salida estándar. El programa debe ser escrito de forma que realice todo el intercambio de datos a través de la salida y la entrada estándar.

Puedes encontrar información en:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl

http://www6.uniovi.es/tcl/tutorial/cap23.html